# FIlter by id an array of array angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an Array of customers.Each customer has an array of Field objects.I would like to 
filter the Array of customers so I get all the customers that have some specific Field.The customer array looks like that.

```
[{"id":236,
 "username":"Tsakos Ntinidis",
 "email":"taskos.a@gmail.com",
 "fields":[{"id":2,"name":"Entrepreneurship"},
                {"id":16,"name":"Sciences (Math, Physics, Chemistry etc)"}, 
                {"id":3,"name":"Engineering"},
                {"id":18,"name":"Journalism"}],
                "hasVideo":false,
                "profileDescription":null,"isNew":false},
 {"id":237,
 "username":"Nick Brown",
 "email":"nikk@gmail.com",
 "fields":[{"id":1,"name":"IT"},
                {"id":16,"name":"Sciences (Math, Physics, Chemistry etc)"}, 
                {"id":18,"name":"Journalism"}],
                "hasVideo":false,
                "profileDescription":null}]
```

and the list that populates the field select field is:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Finance"},{"id":2,"name":"Entrepreneurship"},{"id":3,"name":"Engineering"},{"id":4,"name":"Economics"}]
```

And the html for the customer table is this:

```
 <select  ng-model="search.fields.field.id" ng-options="field.id as field.name for field in fields">
</select>

 <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers | orderBy:predicate:reverse | filter:search" ng-     controller="Controller">
                    <td class="id">{{customer.id}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{customer.userName}}</a></td>
 </tr>
```

My main problem is the array is empty after I filter so apparently something goes wrong.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see here http://jsbin.com/cozasamusinu/1/edit
change select to

```
<select  ng-model="search.fields.id" ng-options="field.id as field.name for field in fields">
</select>
```

and in your reapeater

```
<tr ng-repeat="customer in customers |filter :{fields:search.fields.id}:true">
```

just now in your fileds array you've `{ id:1 name:Finance}` and in `{user id:1 name:IT}`

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning but i filter the list with other parameters as well 

<input type="text" class="filters" ng-model="search.userName" placeholder="Filter by Surename"/>